# How to debug Spring Injected Classes

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, debugging, groovy

I have an web application (JSP and Servlet) running under caucho resin sever in my localhost. I use eclipse (Juno) as my IDE and tried to remote debug my application. The debugger seems fine stepping into the JSP files and Java classes (e.g. index.jsp, Login.java, etc).

However, I wasn't able to step into some parts of my code injected using the SpringApplicationContext.getBean() method. For example I can't step into the following line:

```
IMyMapper myMapper = SpringApplicationContext.getBean("myMapper", IMyMapper.class);
```

The implementation of the interface myMapper is a groovy class injected using Spring. the groovy class MyMapper contains a method that I want to debug:

```
MyMapper.iWantToDebugThisMethod()
```

I already put a breakpoint inside the groovy class (e.g. iWantToDebugThisMethod) but eclipse wasn't able to stop on the breakpoint.

Is there a way that I can debug (step into) my groovy class injected using Spring?

Thanks a lot for your response.